# How can I make sure a certain string resource is used on release builds?

Tags: android

I have a constants string resource file on Android.

I have two strings:

```
<!-- temp test -->
<!--<string name="abc">id</string>-->
<!-- production -->
<string name="abc">id</string>
```

I only use the `temp test` one periodically. When I do that I uncomment it, and I comment the `production` one.

The other day I almost release to my beta users the `temp test` one. Is there any way I can make my apk build for release fail if it detects that somehow? I can add attributes to the string or something that would make it clear.

I could programmatically do this by checking if I am on `debug` and use one or the other but I don't want to use `temp test` except for on some infrequent occasions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have 2 versions of `strings.xml` - debug specific one in `src/debug/res/values` and release one in `src/release/res/values`

Comment: That is very clever. Thank you.

Comment: I don’t know if it’s clever, but it’s _the correct Android way to do it_.